# The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

latestAll S3 bucket file is displayed, but when I upload file then error is generate.

I have ARN and instance profile.

```
use Aws\Credentials\CredentialProvider;
use Aws\Credentials\InstanceProfileProvider;
use Aws\Credentials\AssumeRoleCredentialProvider;
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\Sts\StsClient;

$profile = new InstanceProfileProvider();
$ARN = ""; // MY ARN
$sessionName = "s3-access-example";

$assumeRoleCredentials = new AssumeRoleCredentialProvider([
    'client' => new StsClient([
        'region' => "ap-east-1",
        'version' => "latest",
        'credentials' => $profile
    ]),
    'assume_role_params' => [
        'RoleArn' => $ARN,
        'RoleSessionName' => $sessionName,
    ],
]);

$provider = CredentialProvider::memoize($assumeRoleCredentials);

$this->s3hd = S3Client::factory([
    'credentials' => $provider,
    'version' => "latest",
    'region' => "ap-east-1"
]);

public function upload($name, $file, $type, $Bucket = false)
{
    if (! $Bucket) {
        $Bucket = $this->bucket;
    }
    $result = $this->s3hd->putObject([
        'Bucket' => $Bucket,
        'Key' => $name,
        'SourceFile' => $file,
        'ContentType' => $type,
        'ACL' => 'public-read'
    ]);
    $this->s3hd->waitUntil('ObjectExists', [
        'Bucket' => $Bucket,
        'Key' => $name
    ]);
    return $result;
}
```

> Message: Error executing "PutObject" on `error file url here`; AWS HTTP error: Client error: PUT `error file url here` resulted in a 400 Bad Request` response: InvalidTokenThe provided token is malformed or other (truncated...) InvalidToken (client): The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid. - InvalidTokenThe provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid.

Comment: Which line is generating the error? I can't see a `PutObject` command in your code. It appears that your code is very similar to [Using a Credential Provider - AWS SDK for PHP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_credentials_provider.html). Not sure if this is related to your error, but the example on that page has values for `version` and `region` whereas your code does not.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I updated code.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein it is already working before with access key and secret key. But now i have to use IAM credential ARN instead if access / secret keys.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean. What did you change for Access Key vs Role? And why do you not have a `region` and `version` in `new StsClient()`?

Comment: Yes i have region and version, I have to access s3 bucket using ARN & Instance Profile (IAM credential) instead of access / secret keys.
If i used access / secret keys then it's already working, but now i have to access it without keys using IAM credential.

Comment: Where is your code running (eg on an EC2 instance)? To call `AssumeRole`, you need a set of credentials to identify who you are, so that AWS can confirm that you are entitled to assume the role. Thus, you still need a way to provide those credentials. If your code is running on an EC2 instance, then you can assign the role directly to the instance and the SDK will automatically find and use those permissions.

Comment: If i call $this->s3hd->listBuckets() it return `Message: is_readable(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/share/httpd/.aws/config) is not within the allowed path(s)`, But i have no access/secreat keys then why i am set this config.

Answer (score 25):

In my case. I was trying through CLI.

1. I configured AWS cli by running

> ```
> aws configure
> ```

2. Inside `~/.aws/credentials`, look for `session_token`. If you have the `session_token`. Then update it.
   Otherwise remove `session_token` and try again.

And Voila It worked!

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me when nothing else was working.

Comment: I deleted both "credentials" and "config" files found under the "~/.aws/" directory. Then I re ran the "aws configure" and it resolved the issue.

Comment: Thats what worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because Hong Kong (ap-east-1) is not enabled by default. You need to enable it in the AWS console if you have the correct permissions, then try again.

See the [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande-manage.html#rande-manage-enable) for instructions on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I am using s3cmd and based on the [above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63874456/2223106) I was able to solve by deleting the `.s3cmd` file and reconfiguring (`s3cmd --configure`), which cleared the `access_token`:

```
diff .s3cfg previous_s3cmd

< access_token =
---
> access_token = vkp1Jf\etc...
```

Also increased the chunk sizes:

```
< recv_chunk = 65536
---
> recv_chunk = 4096

< send_chunk = 65536
---
> send_chunk = 4096
```

And I guess I had previously opted for https requests, as opposed to the (current) default:

```
< use_https = True
---
> use_https = False
```

## Success

```
Success. Your access key and secret key worked fine :-)

Now verifying that encryption works...
Success. Encryption and decryption worked fine :-)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to update the aws configuration file.
You can follow the following steps.
In local command line terminal:

> open ~./aws

Open the credentials file and update the values for the following 3 entries:

> aws_access_key_id
>
> aws_secret_access_key
>
> aws_session_token

You can get these values from AWS console.
Hope it helps!!